# More effective and short JS code?

Tags: javascript

I need some advices in this task.

We've got this structure:

```
const scenes = {
  'Node1': {
    'scene1': [
      {
        nodeKey: 'cccc',
        category: 'user',
      },
      {
        nodeKey: 'eeee',
        category: 'interface',
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

I need to make this:

```
let result = {
  'Node1': {
    'scene1': {
      'cccc': {
        nodeKey: 'cccc',
        category: 'user',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I use the reduce function to make it work. But I think it can be done more efficiently. Thanks!

My code (updated):

```
function makeNewStructure(scenes) {
  return Object.keys(scenes).reduce((prevNode, currentNode) => ({
      ...prevNode, 
      [currentNode]: Object.keys(scenes[currentNode]).reduce((prevScene, currentScene) => ({
        ...prevScene, 
        [currentScene]: scenes[currentNode][currentScene].reduce((previous, current) => ({
            ...previous,
            [current.nodeKey]: current
        }),{})
      }), {})
  }), {})
}
```

Or we can make it this way. But I think with the reduce (only) function is better anyway. Hmm

```
function makeNewStructure(scenes) {
  return Object.keys(scenes).reduce((prevNode, currentNode) => {
    let node = {}
    let currentScenesInNode = scenes[currentNode]

    for (let scene in currentScenesInNode) {
        let updatedScene = {}
      currentScenesInNode[scene].forEach(item => {
        return updatedScene[item.nodeKey] = item
      })

        node[scene] = updatedScene
    }

    return {
      ...prevNode, 
      [currentNode]: node
    }
  }, {})
}
```

Comment: in your case I would care of word *readable* way more than *efficient*. A couple of nested `forEach` would be so much more readable than this ES6 circus... I mean, it's cool to use ES6 possibilities, but it shouldn't be done against readability. Also, a couple of functions with proper names would decrease the density of that code, again in a more readable manner

Comment: @smnbbrv Thank you! I will try to make it more readable.

Comment: I got stuck when I see "ccccc"

Comment: @DmitryPetrov probably your question should be asked instead at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Chase Just an example ;)

Comment: @Chase haha, 5 times c vs 4 times c... Good catch, I haven't seen it at first :D I've got stuck at `...prevNode, [current]`, what is `current`? (I guess `currentNode`)

Comment: fixed, sorry guys)

Comment: by any chance, is `JSON.parse` used to get the scenes?

Comment: @Slai Don't know, it's just synthetic structure from my collegue

Answer (score 0):

In the lazy less efficient version, `JSON.parse` or `JSON.stringify` can be used to enumerate all values :

```js
const scenes = { 'Node1': { 'scene1': [ { nodeKey: 'cccc', category: 'user'     , }, 
                                        { nodeKey: 'eeee', category: 'interface', }, ] } }

const result = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(scenes), (key, val) => 
    Array.isArray(val) ? val.reduce((o, v) => (o[v.nodeKey] = v, o), {}) : val) 

console.log( result )
```

Otherwise, recursive function or JS library can be used for similar approach.